# iPad: Access UIPopoverController from embeded UINavigationController

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have a UIPopoverController with embeded UINavigationController. The navigation controller has MyViewController as a root controller.
The question is, how do I access the UIPopoverController from MyViewController?
I would like a button in the navigation controller to close the popover when pressed.

Something like this:

```
[self.navigationController.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in MyViewController you'll need to create a UIPopoverController property, and set that property to your popoverController when you display the navigation controller.

you should then be able to call the dismiss method on the UIPopoverController property.